# how to buy and send an itunes card as a gift?

Tags: itunes-store

How do I gift an iTunes card to my friend in Ghana? I do not want one for myself. I have never heard or used one.

Answer (score 0):

You can either buy one in a commercial center and ship it or send one directly by mail.

Concerning the second option, all you have to do is to scroll to the bottom of the **Apps** category of your iPhone App Store application and tap `Send a Gift`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your local store
2. Look for an iTunes Gift Card
3. Purchase it
4. Ship it
5. Wait for a thank you letter

Source: Common Sense

---

Or you can follow [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201783) tutorial to send e-gifts

For more information: https://www.apple.com/shop/gift-cards